# Appium list of objects is 0

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, appium

I'm trying to describe an item in RecyclerView as an object and the put those available items in the list, but the list size is always returned as 0:

```
public class DealsListLayout {

   private Waiter waiter;

   @FindBy(id = "com.deals.test:id/deals_item_content_view")
   private List<DealsItem> listOfElements;

   public DealsListLayout() {
        waiter = new Waiter();
        init();
        listOfElements = new ArrayList<>();
        printInfo("Size " + listOfElements.size());
   }

   private void init() {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }
}
```

And the part which describes the DealsItem class looks like this:

```
public class DealsItem {

    @FindBy(id = "com.deals.test/deals_item_asset_name_textview")
    private MobileElement dealName;
    @FindBy(id = "com.deals.test:id/deals_item_time_open_textview")
    private MobileElement dealStartTime;

    public DealsItem() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
}
```

So the question is why the `listOfElements` is returned empty. And if I do:

```
listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.id("com.deals.test:id/deals_item_content_view"));
```

It returns me exactly 2 elements on the screen which I am having right now.
Any suggestions?
Please if its duplicate - please send me a link to the answer, because I googled it several times and find no answer.

Comment: You can't nest FindBy's like that.  Your code is all over the place with potential problems/errors.  All you really need to do is what you did with the listOfElements line but assign -that- to a List<AndroidElement> (or List<MobileElement>) in your FindBy

Comment: @DebanjanB yeah that was from example, fixed it

Comment: @BillHileman sorry what kind of problems/errors? Why I can't use pagefactory? And it works perfectly if I assign to List<DealsItem>.

Comment: If your list size is returning zero, then apparently it's not working.  One of your elements in the DealsItem class is by ID but has no ID in it's locator - probably just a typo.  Since I can't really see what your end goal is, I can't say what your best solution is, but while your FindBy might not be returning an error, I don't think it's going to work - it's just going to be an empty array, which is exactly what you're reporting.  I just noticed that someone else spotted the ID thing, so disregard that.

Comment: @BillHileman he noted that and it was really a typo in the question, not my code. I don't know if you read the whole question, but if I do the findElements(By.id()) way it works, the question is why it doesn't work with FindBy

Comment: Because your list type is not of type MobileElement.

Comment: Well, I found out what was the problem. AppiumFieldDecorator is not able to work with nested objects, and think I will need to write my own custom decorator, but for now I moved to Yandex HtmlElements, right now it works as a charm.

Comment: Read about PageObject anti-pattern, with design above your tests give more potencial issues and complexity, but should be easy to read and main. PageObject is good, but PageFactory is a mess :)

Comment: @dmle actually I am using PageObject. And appium decorator doesn't support what I want, so I moved to HtmlElements. If you wish I can show reworked code in answer.